# Redirect a page after previous page-redirect

Tags: php, html, redirect

I am trying, as the title says, to *Redirect a page after previous page-redirect*, each one at a certain time, e.g. After 5 seconds redirect to a certain page, after more 5 seconds redirect to another page, I don't know if it is possible.

If I still wasn't clear I am trying to access a page `www.site.com/photo1.png` then after this page is accessed, and after a certain time go to another page `www.site.com/photo2.png` and so on `photo3,photo4,photo5...`

Code used is PHP. Something like that:

```
<?php
$u=99; 
$b=0;
while($b<$u){
    $b++;
    header("www.site.com/photo". $b .".png");
}
<?
```

But it isn't even going to the site and, obviously, after it accessed the site this code wouldn't be runned anymore.

Forgive my newbie-ness.

Comment: You can try `sleep(5);` or use jQuery.

Comment: Is there any option to use javascript? I mean, do you really need to do that using PHP?

Comment: Well, you can use Javascript, but if you know it in PHP it would be better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a couple ways of doing this.
if you use a php you could do something like this

oops forgot to use session_start(); (put it in now)

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['photo'])){
     $_SESSION['photo'] = 0;
}else{
     $_SESSION['photo']++;
}

header("www.site.com/photo". $_SESSION['photo'] .".png");

$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";//or use something to generate a random amount of seconds
header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page");
```

or load your website and let jquery/javascript change the picture every X-seconds without having to go on a page reload rampage!(i would pick jquery/javascript solution)

edit:
sure this is a working example. cool thing if you do it with javascript/jquery you can add all kind of effects

```
<!--your html -->
<img id="example" src="/assets/img/wallpaper1.jpg"/>
<script>
    var counter = 1;

    function loadNewImage(){
            counter++;
            //set the new image
        $("#example").attr('src','/assets/img/wallpaper' + counter + '.jpg');
    }

    //call the function in 5 seconds
    setInterval(loadNewImage, 5000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but what was the purpose of the loopit()? Seemed useless to me

Comment: sorry my bad, ignore loopit, its removed now

Answer (score -1):

Try adding location into the parameter. Like this: 
`header("location: www...");`